# powershell, websession name issue

Tags: powershell

```
$menuChoice = $null
$webSite = "https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/default.aspx"
$year = (Get-Date).Year
$month = (Get-Date).Month
if ($month -lt "10") {
    $month = "0" + $month
}
$metalsXML = Get-ChildItem "\\Company-040538\c$\BWI\XML"
$vincheckXML = Get-ChildItem "\\Company-040538\c$\BWI\XMLNew\Vincheck"

function loginToRAPID() {    
    $access = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $webSite -SessionVariable login
    $form = $access.forms[0]    
    $Global:organization = Read-Host "`tEnter the organization"
    $username = Read-Host "`tEnter the username"
    $password = Read-Host "`tEnter the password"
    $form.fields["organization"] = $organization
    $form.fields["Username"] = $username
    $form.fields["Password"] = $password    
    $Global:login = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/" + $form.Action) -WebSession $login -Method post -Body $form.Fields              
}

function uploadXML() {    
    if ($login.AllElements | where {$_.innerhtml -like "Please provide your username and password for authentication."}) {
        Write-Host "`tLog in failed, please try again! `n" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {        
        $info = $login.AllElements | where {$_.tagName -contains "span"}
        $account = $info.innerhtml | Select-Object -First 3      
        Write-Host "`tLogged in as" $account "`n" -ForegroundColor Green 
        $upload = $login.AllElements.InnerHtml | Where-Object {$_ -match 'url="(administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx\?.*?)"'} | 
            ForEach-Object {$matches[1]}   
        $uploadPage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/bwident/pawnshop/" + $upload[0]) -WebSession $login                                       
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error, and it's saying it's related to the websession, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using the same websession ($login) to login and access a page.

"Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'WebSession'. Cannot convert the value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject" to type
 "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession".
 At U:\PowerShell\BWI\BWI.ps1:40 char:84
This is the websession with the error message.

`$uploadPage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/bwident/pawnshop/" + $upload[0]) -WebSession $login`

Comment: In `$access = ..`, you are correctly assigning  the session to the variable `$login` (type:`WebRequestSession`). In `$Global:login =..` you are then overwriting this session variable with a response (type: `HtmlWebResponseObject`) so it no longer contains your session. Use a different variable name e.g. `$Global:loginResponse`

Comment: Thank you @gms0ulman, I'll try that and post response

Comment: I have $loginResponse for $global:login, and $login for $uploadPage, but, it's taking me to the login page, it looks like it doesn't know that I'm already logged into the website.  How does it make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you're using the functions. Checking the [`Invoke-WebRequest` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), it doesn't look like there is a way to set the `$login` SessionVariable scope to Global.

So instead, return this variable in the `loginToRAPID` function and pass it to the `uploadXML` function. As otherwise the `uploadXML` does not have access to the same session. This is better practice than setting variable scope to Global where possible.

Below, I've added the parameter as `$session`. And changed `$login` to `$loginResponse` in places.

```
$menuChoice = $null
$webSite = "https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/default.aspx"
$year = (Get-Date).Year
$month = (Get-Date).Month
if ($month -lt "10") {
    $month = "0" + $month
}
$metalsXML = Get-ChildItem "\\Company-040538\c$\BWI\XML"
$vincheckXML = Get-ChildItem "\\Company-040538\c$\BWI\XMLNew\Vincheck"

function loginToRAPID() {    
    $access = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $webSite -SessionVariable login
    $form = $access.forms[0]    
    $Global:organization = Read-Host "`tEnter the organization"
    $username = Read-Host "`tEnter the username"
    $password = Read-Host "`tEnter the password"
    $form.fields["organization"] = $organization
    $form.fields["Username"] = $username
    $form.fields["Password"] = $password    
    $Global:loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/" + $form.Action) -WebSession $login -Method post -Body $form.Fields

    return $login              
}

function uploadXML($session = loginToRAPID) {    
    if ($loginResponse.AllElements | where {$_.innerhtml -like "Please provide your username and password for authentication."}) {
        Write-Host "`tLog in failed, please try again! `n" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {        
        $info = $loginResponse.AllElements | where {$_.tagName -contains "span"}
        $account = $info.innerhtml | Select-Object -First 3      
        Write-Host "`tLogged in as" $account "`n" -ForegroundColor Green 
        $upload = $loginResponse.AllElements.InnerHtml | Where-Object {$_ -match 'url="(administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx\?.*?)"'} | 
            ForEach-Object {$matches[1]}   
        $uploadPage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/bwident/pawnshop/" + $upload[0]) -WebSession $session
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but `return $login` will leave that value in the output, plus, I'm still getting the same results as before.

Comment: @MattDamoz Yes, that's intentional. Please see edit above `function uploadXML($session = loginToRAPID)` as workaround. How are you currently calling the functions? I would have thought `$mysession = loginToRAPID; uploadXML -session $mysession` would be possible?